# Is there an equivilant of phpinfo for jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

server side background, getting deeper and deeper into client side.

I've got a site with a lot of legacy that I'm new to, and I'm just trying to get a handle on how things are working/what's available.

Is there a way to have jquery tell me(for a page/pages) all its current info and any plugins it can/is use/ing, similar to what phpinfo does?

Comment: `console.log(window);`

Comment: For a list of plugins, you can check the loaded "Scripts" in your browser's dev tools. Or, possibly scan for `<script>`s with `"jquery"` in the `src`. But, plugins don't really register themselves with jQuery for it to tell you about them.

Comment: visioN hmm, that's a lot of info, true, but not exactly what I'm looking for.  @JonathanLonowski  that's too bad, I do see where things are coming in from, sometimes.. after searching through several layers of includes and permissions. I was hoping the page could tell me it's final tally.

Comment: `console.log( $() )` will display the jQuery object and all its associated methods. In my Chrome browser, at least, plugin methods seem to appear at the top of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some proof of concept how you can get names for all plugins

```
var plugins = (function() {
    var plugins = [];

    for(var plugin in jQuery.fn) {
        plugins.push(plugin)
    }

    return plugins;
}());

var filterValue = ['constructor', 'init', 'add', 'parents'] // // you must add all standard methods here

filterValue.forEach(function(value) {
    var position = function(value) {
        return plugins.indexOf(value);
    }
    while(position(value) >= 0) {
        plugins.splice(position(value), 1)
    }
})


console.log(plugins)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following for jQuery

`console.log( jQuery.fn.jquery );`

Comment: That only outputs the version, not any additional plugins or information.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, No jQuery does not have a mechanism that lists installed plug-ins.

jQuery does not keep such a registry of installed plugins.  The jQuery plugin mechanism is to just add a method to the jQuery prototype (right along-side all the other jQuery methods).  So, there's no separate list of which methods have been added by some outside agent (e.g. a plug-in).  In addition, there's no one-to-one correspondence between methods and a particular plug-in as a single plug-in could add multiple methods.

It would be possible to create a master list (for any specific jQuery version) of what methods are there by default and then enumerate a jQuery object to find out which methods have been added since then, but you'd have to create that master list ahead of time and store it or create the master list immediately after jQuery was loaded before any plug-ins were loaded.

You can always test to see if any specific jQuery plug-in is loaded by just checking to see if any of its signature methods are available on a jQuery object.

So, if you really just wanted to know which of 10 plugins happen to be available in any given page, you could write a quick function that would test for each of the 10 plugins (by looking for the existence of known methods in those plugins) and would return a list of the ones installed, but this has to be done with specific knowledge of each plugin as there is no "generic plugin identification mechanism" since a plug-in is nothing more than a piece of code that adds methods to the jQuery prototype.  It doesn't actually have any identity of its own.